# Gnome3 predefining virtual desktops

Tags: virtual-desktop, gnome3

I've been a loyal user of Gnome 2 for many years now. I wanted to try Gnome 3.Many things in G3 don't bother me at all; however, not being able to predefine virtual desktops really erks the hell out of me. How do I disable dynamic desktops?

My work flow over the past years leaves me with a framework.

- Desktop1: Windows
- Desktop6: IRC & Server Monitors

This gives me the ability to play with the remaining 4 desktops.

How can I predefine my 6 desktops so I can immediately assign windows to them, without having to grow to 6 desktops?

Answer (score 4):

*Answer to this old question that was not answered, but you still get here from search engines so..*

In **Gnome 3**, if you don't have **Gnome Tweak Tools** already, install it with **`sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`**.

When you have it, start it up and go to **Workspaces** tab, change Dynamic to **Static**, and **set amount of Workspaces** and weither you want it on primary display only or not.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

There are a new set of extensions which let you get some of the gnome2 look and feel back. One of those lets you disable the dynamic desktops and instead lets you have a fixed no of static desktops.

You can find there here

http://intgat.tigress.co.uk/rmy/extensions/index.html

And there's a tutorial how to use the extensions.

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/new-gnome-shell-extensions-that-provide.html

Comment: Extension does not work on Ubuntu 11.10 in the "Gnome" environment.

Comment: Ubuntu Unity? That's not Gnome.