# Is there any supported migration path from Fedora to Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, fedora

I'd like to get off Fedora: between it's a bad bug tracker and [package management](https://superuser.com/questions/290363/rpm-thinks-something-is-removed-cant-remove-yet-thinks-something-is-installed), [networking problems](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=708624), and adoption of [Gnome 3, which doesn't even support virtual desktops](https://superuser.com/questions/287693/gnome3-predefining-virtual-desktops), I'm rather sick of it.

All that I really want is the stuff in my home directory. Does Ubuntu offer anything from the install CD, which can leave the basic gnome folders, `~/Documents` `~/Music` `~/Videos` alone and wipe everything else: including configuration files? Or, do I need to get out another hard drive and back all this stuff up? All I want is data in one users home directory, and install to the current partition setup.

Comment: The change is about to get a bit easier due to [this](http://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/devel/2011-May/151663.html). "I suppose UID/GID_MIN=1000 is more common (other distros, upstream). We are not 
in situation that 500 IDs for system accounts ought to be enough for anybody."

Answer (score 6):

If you have `/home` on a separate partition then you can just tell the respective installer to not format that partition and instead just mount it at `/home`. If you didn't put it on a separate partition... then you should have put it on a separate partition.

Comment: I couldn't really tell you one way or another, apparently [Fedora has found a way to make basic partitioning an major issue too](http://superuser.com/questions/290369/confusing-fedora-partitions-on-fresh-install). I think vendor lock in still remains from RH.

Comment: If you truly believe that Ubuntu will free you from lock-in, then...

Answer (score 0):

Fedora is RPM based, and Ubuntu APT based.

A migration path isn't going to be an easy thing.